# Can't import Appcelerator Studio sample: Fatal Error

Tags: appcelerator-studio

When I try to import, say the Employee Directory from the Studio Dashboard, I get this error:

fatal: unable to find remote helper for https

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s226B.png)

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Git clone is getting failed due to local internal issues.

You can identify the root cause using the below command from the terminal.

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone --depth 1 --progress -- https://github.com/appcelerator-se/corporate-directory.git
```

This will import the Employee Directory app with trace enabled.